# Gradient of dot product of vector times itself.

Tags: geometry, vectors, differential

I know that:

$$
\nabla(a\cdot b) = (a\cdot\nabla)b +(b\cdot \nabla)a + a\times(\nabla\times b)+ b\times (\nabla \times a)
$$

and also that:

$$
\nabla(a\cdot b) = (\nabla a)\cdot b + (\nabla b)\cdot a
$$

With this in mind I want to find the "simplest" expression for $\nabla(a\cdot a)$ other that
$$
\nabla(a\cdot a) = 2(\nabla a)\cdot a 
$$
I need to avoid the use of matrices ($\nabla a$).

Thanks in advance...

Comment: How about using your first equation with $b=a$?

Comment: I can use it, but no identity seems to simplify any terms... This is what I want to know: is it possible to simplify the first equation assuming $b=a$?

Comment: Do you want to go beyond $$\nabla(a\cdot a) = 2(a\nabla)a + 2a\times(\nabla\times a)$$?

Comment: If it is possible, yes... I dont want the matrix in the first terms of the RHS.

Comment: I am a bit puzzled by these identities - what are $a,b$ in the first place, vector or scalar fields?

Comment: $a, b$ are vector fields. I am interested in the particular case: $b=a$